# Angular, Displays a list multiple times on the same html page, that is updated each round of the loop through c#

Tags: html, angular, typescript, asp.net-web-api

I want to display a list as the options in select when in each round in the loop the list will be updated according to the current div
It works in terms of concept, but the html is updated only once according to the last entry in the list and does not display a different list for each loop rotation

my html

```
<div *ngFor="let item of listConstraint" [value]="item.id">
        <p>{{item.name_constraint}}</p>
        <select>
            <option *ngFor="let item1 of listConstraintDetails" [value]="item1.id">
                {{item1.name_constraint}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

my ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AjaxRequestService } from 'src/app/services/Request/ajax-request.service';
import { ConstraintKind } from 'src/app/class/constraintKind';
import { ConstraintDetails } from 'src/app/class/constraint-details';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-constraints',
  templateUrl: './constraints.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./constraints.component.css']
})
export class ConstraintsComponent implements OnInit {
  constraintForm: FormGroup;
  listConstraint: ConstraintKind[] = [];
  listConstraintDetails: ConstraintDetails[] = [];
  constructor(private http: AjaxRequestService, private httpClient: HttpClient, private route: Router) {

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.GetConstraintsKind();
  }
  GetConstraintsKind() {
    return this.http.GetConstraintsKind().subscribe(data => {
      this.listConstraint = data;
      data.forEach(element => {
        this.GetConstraintsDetails(element.id);
      })
      console.log(data);
    })
  }
  GetConstraintsDetails(constraintId) {
    return this.http.GetConstraintsDetails(constraintId).subscribe(data => {
      this.listConstraintDetails = data;
      console.log(data);
    })
  }
}
```

my functions ajax service

```
  GetConstraintsKind() {
    return this.http.get<any>('http://localhost:11818/Api/Constraint/getConstraintKind', { headers: this.header });
  }
  GetConstraintsDetails(constraintId: number) {
    return this.http.get<ConstraintDetails[]>('http://localhost:11818/Api/Constraint/GetConstraintsDetails/' + constraintId);
  }
```

the server works well, and send the correct data, but the html display the same list the whole time
Thanks so much for any help

Answer (score 0):

You are performing  inner loop operation all at **ngOnInit** inside a single array, thats overwriting previously fetched data in the **listConstraintDetails** array.

What you want can be achieved, if you modify your code a little, like this

```js
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.GetConstraintsKind();
  }
  GetConstraintsKind() {
    return this.http.GetConstraintsKind().subscribe(data => {
      this.listConstraint = data;
    })
  }
  GetConstraintsDetails(constraintId):ConstraintDetails[]{
  let itemsarr: ConstraintDetails[] = [];

  if(constraintId)
  {
   this.http.GetConstraintsDetails(constraintId).subscribe(data => {
   itemsarr = data;
   })
  }
   return itemsarr;
  }
```

And your html would get modified like

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of listConstraint" [value]="item.id">
        <p>{{item.name_constraint}}</p>
        <select>
            <option *ngFor="let item1 of GetConstraintsDetails(item.id)" [value]="item1.id">
                {{item1.name_constraint}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, but I tried it and it does not work, it creates an endless loop in the function in Ts GetConstraintsDetails

Comment: Please check with the updated code, removed the async pipe and put a check of null value against constraintId.

Comment: shall you please show what error you get? where your code gets stuck? because theoretically there is nothing wrong in this approach...

Comment: it creates an endless loop in the function in Ts GetConstraintsDetails, i put   console.log(constraintId) there; and the result: 1,2,3,4,5,6 and again 1.2.3.4.5.6.......

Answer (score 0):

my html

```
  <div *ngFor="let item of listConstraint" [attr.data-value]="item.id">
            <p>{{item.name_constraint}}</p>
            <select *ngIf="constraintDetails[item.id]">
                <option *ngFor="let item1 of constraintDetails[item.id]" [value]="item1.id">
                    {{item1.name_constraint}}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
```

my ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AjaxRequestService } from 'src/app/services/Request/ajax-request.service';
import { ConstraintKind } from 'src/app/class/constraintKind';
import { ConstraintDetails } from 'src/app/class/constraint-details';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-constraints',
  templateUrl: './constraints.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./constraints.component.css']
})
export class ConstraintsComponent implements OnInit {
  constraintForm: FormGroup;
  listConstraint: ConstraintKind[] = [];
  listConstraintDetails: ConstraintDetails[] = [];
  constraintDetails = {};

  constructor(private http: AjaxRequestService, private httpClient: HttpClient, private route: Router) {

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.GetConstraintsKind();
  }
  GetConstraintsKind() {
    return this.http.GetConstraintsKind().subscribe(data => {
      this.listConstraint = data;
      for (let i = 0; i < this.listConstraint.length; i++) {
        const element = this.listConstraint[i].id;
        this.http.GetConstraintsDetails(element)
          .subscribe(cd => {
            this.constraintDetails[element] = cd;
            console.log(this.constraintDetails)
          });
      }
    })
  }

  GetConstraintsDetails(constraintId): ConstraintDetails[] {
    console.log(constraintId);
    let itemsarr: ConstraintDetails[] = [];

    if (!itemsarr) {
      this.http.GetConstraintsDetails(constraintId).subscribe(data => {
        itemsarr = data;
      })
    }
    return itemsarr;
  }

}
```